# Convert jquery Script into Prototype Scriptaculous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Hi I hAVE my code here in jquery for my footer chat panel And it is conflict with Scriptaculous. I want it to convert into pure js or Using Prototype Scriptaculous.
Any Help?
Thank you!

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$.fn.adjustPanel = function(){ 
    $(this).find("ul, .subpanel").css({ 'height' : 'auto'}); 

    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Get the height of the browser viewport
    var panelsub = $(this).find(".subpanel").height(); //Get the height of subpanel 
    var panelAdjust = windowHeight - 100; //Viewport height - 100px (Sets max height of subpanel)
    var ulAdjust =  panelAdjust - 25; //Calculate ul size after adjusting sub-panel (27px is the height of the base panel)

    if ( panelsub >= panelAdjust ) {     //If subpanel is taller than max height...
        $(this).find(".subpanel").css({ 'height' : panelAdjust }); //Adjust subpanel to max height
        $(this).find("ul").css({ 'height' : ulAdjust}); //Adjust subpanel ul to new size
    }
    else if ( panelsub < panelAdjust ) { //If subpanel is smaller than max height...
        $(this).find("ul").css({ 'height' : 'auto'}); //Set subpanel ul to auto (default size)
    }
};  
//Execute function on load
$("#chatpanel").adjustPanel(); //Run the adjustPanel function on #chatpanel
$("#alertpanel").adjustPanel(); //Run the adjustPanel function on #alertpanel

//Each time the viewport is adjusted/resized, execute the function
$(window).resize(function () { 
    $("#chatpanel").adjustPanel();
    $("#alertpanel").adjustPanel();
});


    //Click event on Chat Panel + Alert Panel   
$("#chatpanel a:first, #alertpanel a:first,#alertpanel2 a:first,#likes a:first,#twiter a:first").click(function() { //If clicked on the first link of #chatpanel and #alertpanel...
    if($(this).next(".subpanel").is(':visible')){ //If subpanel is already active...
        $(this).next(".subpanel").hide(); //Hide active subpanel
        $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //Remove active class on the subpanel trigger
    }
    else { //if subpanel is not active...
        $(".subpanel").hide(); //Hide all subpanels
        $(this).next(".subpanel").toggle(); //Toggle the subpanel to make active
        $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //Remove active class on all subpanel trigger
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); //Toggle the active class on the subpanel trigger
    }
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});

//Click event outside of subpanel
$(document).click(function() { //Click anywhere and...
    $(".subpanel").hide(); //hide subpanel
    $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //remove active class on subpanel trigger
});
$('.subpanel ul').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevents the subpanel ul from closing on click
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [use jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Comment: @devzone: are you using `jQuery` instead of `$`, and including `jQuery.noConflict();`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Example:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code above with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.noConflict();



 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$(document).ready(function(){


$.fn.adjustPanel = function(){ 
    $(this).find("ul, .subpanel").css({ 'height' : 'auto'}); 

    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); //Get the height of the browser viewport
    var panelsub = $(this).find(".subpanel").height(); //Get the height of subpanel 
    var panelAdjust = windowHeight - 100; //Viewport height - 100px (Sets max height of subpanel)
    var ulAdjust =  panelAdjust - 25; //Calculate ul size after adjusting sub-panel (27px is the height of the base panel)

    if ( panelsub >= panelAdjust ) {     //If subpanel is taller than max height...
        $(this).find(".subpanel").css({ 'height' : panelAdjust }); //Adjust subpanel to max height
        $(this).find("ul").css({ 'height' : ulAdjust}); //Adjust subpanel ul to new size
    }
    else if ( panelsub < panelAdjust ) { //If subpanel is smaller than max height...
        $(this).find("ul").css({ 'height' : 'auto'}); //Set subpanel ul to auto (default size)
    }
};  
//Execute function on load
$("#chatpanel").adjustPanel(); //Run the adjustPanel function on #chatpanel
$("#alertpanel").adjustPanel(); //Run the adjustPanel function on #alertpanel

//Each time the viewport is adjusted/resized, execute the function
$(window).resize(function () { 
    $("#chatpanel").adjustPanel();
    $("#alertpanel").adjustPanel();
});


    //Click event on Chat Panel + Alert Panel   
$("#chatpanel a:first, #alertpanel a:first,#alertpanel2 a:first,#likes a:first,#twiter a:first").click(function() { //If clicked on the first link of #chatpanel and #alertpanel...
    if($(this).next(".subpanel").is(':visible')){ //If subpanel is already active...
        $(this).next(".subpanel").hide(); //Hide active subpanel
        $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //Remove active class on the subpanel trigger
    }
    else { //if subpanel is not active...
        $(".subpanel").hide(); //Hide all subpanels
        $(this).next(".subpanel").toggle(); //Toggle the subpanel to make active
        $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //Remove active class on all subpanel trigger
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); //Toggle the active class on the subpanel trigger
    }
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
});

//Click event outside of subpanel
$(document).click(function() { //Click anywhere and...
    $(".subpanel").hide(); //hide subpanel
    $("#footpanel li a").removeClass('active'); //remove active class on subpanel trigger
});
$('.subpanel ul').click(function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); //Prevents the subpanel ul from closing on click
});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

});




    </script>
```